# Stencil-CLI is outdated and won't upgrade

Tags: bigcommerce

I've recently received the following error after running $ stencil start:

```
Error: You are using an outdated version of stencil-cli, please run $ npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli
```

I ran the command but continued to get the error. I'm on Windows 10 and was previously running node 4.7.0. I upgraded to 6.9.3, ran the command again, and still no luck. Any idea why I would still be getting this error?

Comment: UPDATE: I ended up completely uninstalling Node and then reinstalling everything. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue on our end--the error messaging should actually indicate that the store URL provided during `stencil init` is incorrect. Could you check the URL for typos/make sure it's a good URL? Let me know if this helps!

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the issue for me. I'm getting the error for every store that I'm currently working on and all of the URLs are correct. They've been the same since each site has gone live and everything has worked fine up until yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

What version do you get when you run: `stencil --version`? latest is `1.15.1`

You could try removing and reinstalling `stencil-cli`:

`npm uninstall -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli
npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli`

Comment: it says I'm running 1.13.1. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: It's really odd because after re-installing, the very last line in the console is this: + @bigcommerce/stencil-cli@1.15.1
added 1357 packages from 1402 contributors in 47.145s